# How to use two threads in one function?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, thread-safety, threadpool

here I have a function of checkupdate() in which my application check updates available for users, so i need to display two progressdialog one when server is under request(Checking process) and other when synchronization process is ongoing and both the process is done on the load of application.
Now problem is I'm unable to display these two progressdialog boxes, here only the first **thread checking updates** is running and application is terminated.
Waiting for your valuable answers.

```
public void CheckUpdate()
{ 

//----------------Process of checking the updates--------------------------

        try
            {
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Wait", "Checking update...", false, true);
            Thread thr1 = new Thread() 
             {
                 public void run()
                 {
                     int Flag = call.CheckUserUpdate(UsrId);
                     Update = Flag;
                     progressDialog.dismiss();
                     //stop();
                     interrupt();

                 }
             };
             thr1.start();
            }
            catch(final Exception e)
            {

            }
    //---------------Process of Synchronization----------------------------------------------        
            try
            {
             progressDialog1 = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Wait", "Synchronizing...", false, true);
             Thread thr2 = new Thread() 
             {
                 public void run()
                 {
                     if(Update == 1)
                     {
                        SyncData();
                        final int UpdateFlag = 1;
                        call.UpdateUserUpdate(UsrId, UpdateFlag);
                        progressDialog1.dismiss();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        progressDialog1.dismiss();
                    }
                     progressDialog1.dismiss();
                 }
             };
             thr2.start();
            }
            catch(final Exception e)
            {

            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting the new threads causes them to start executing elsewhere.  Your program here starts two threads, gets to the end of `main()` and exits, causing the JVM/OS to kill your newly started threads that never really got a chance to run very far.

You need to add an idle loop (or similar) that yields control on the main thread while the worker threads to their thing, assuming you don't have any work happening on the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Do I understand correctly what you want?

Your UI activitiy has two progressbars which should be updated based on either

1. update check process
2. synchronization process

then you should create a `handler` in your UI activity and use two separate threads one for update check and the other for synchronization check

Both send their progress info to the main thread like:

```
mHandler.obtainMessage(Main_screen.MESSAGE_PGROGRESS_CHANGE_UPDATE, state, -1)
    .sendToTarget();
```

in the other you have

```
mHandler.obtainMessage(Main_screen.MESSAGE_PGROGRESS_CHANGE_SYNCHRINIZATION, state, -1)
    .sendToTarget();
```

In your UI activity you have the handler looking like this...

```
 private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        if (DEBUG)
        Log.i(this.getClass().getSimpleName(),
            "-> "
                + Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2]
                    .getMethodName());
        switch (msg.what) {
        case MESSAGE_PGROGRESS_CHANGE_UPDATE:
        if (DEBUG)
            Log.i(this.getClass().getSimpleName(),
                "  MESSAGE_PGROGRESS_CHANGE_UPDATE: " + msg.arg1);

        // do your update of progressbar or whatever here
        break;
            case MESSAGE_PGROGRESS_CHANGE_SYNCHRINIZATION:
        if (DEBUG)
            Log.i(this.getClass().getSimpleName(),
                "  MESSAGE_PGROGRESS_CHANGE_SYNCHRINIZATION: " + msg.arg1);

        // do your update of progressbar or whatever here
        break;
```